# Python - ibm_db module install : 'link.exe' failed with exit status 1120

Tags: python, db2

Hope all are doing great !!! I am trying to connect my DB2 with python, so that I can develop database transactions through PyCharm.

I have Python installed Python 3.6.1(32 bit version) on my machine.

And, I am trying to install "ibm_db" module to perform DB2 database related transaction from Python, so I ran this command

```
C:\Users\SudipGhosh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32>easy_install ibm_db-2.0.5-py3.3-win32.egg ibm_db-2.0.7.tar.gz

Processing ibm_db-2.0.5-py3.3-win32.egg
removing 'c:\users\sudipghosh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\ibm_db-2.0.5-py3.3-win32.egg' (and everything under it)
creating c:\users\sudipghosh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\ibm_db-2.0.5-py3.3-win32.egg
Extracting ibm_db-2.0.5-py3.3-win32.egg to c:\users\sudipghosh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages
ibm-db 2.0.5 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed c:\users\sudipghosh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\ibm_db-2.0.5-py3.3-win32.egg
Processing dependencies for ibm-db==2.0.5
Searching for ibm-db==2.0.5
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/ibm-db/
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/df/3e/db8ac8d4a2b49c27ad2a90d5b1b9a4673933c4e3dfd777849e7e7e4b8a79/ibm_db-2.0.5.tar.gz#md5=73ed86f4cf423fc608db95403ba988e4
Best match: ibm-db 2.0.5
Processing ibm_db-2.0.5.tar.gz
Writing C:\Users\SUDIPG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-_5givnbi\ibm_db-2.0.5\setup.cfg
Running ibm_db-2.0.5\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir C:\Users\SUDIPG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-_5givnbi\ibm_db-2.0.5\egg-dist-tmp-ay___k95
Detected 32-bit Python
C:\Users\SUDIPG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-_5givnbi\ibm_db-2.0.5\setup.py:52: UserWarning: Detected usage of IBM Data Server Driver package. Ensure you have downloaded 32-bit package of IBM_Data_Server_Driver and retry the ibm_db module install

  warnings.warn(notifyString)
ibm_db.c
ibm_db.c(5326): warning C4018: '<=': signed/unsigned mismatch
ibm_db.c(5330): warning C4018: '<=': signed/unsigned mismatch
ibm_db.c(5342): warning C4018: '<=': signed/unsigned mismatch
ibm_db.c(5456): warning C4018: '<=': signed/unsigned mismatch
ibm_db.c(9643): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'SQLINTEGER' to 'SQLSMALLINT', possible loss of data
   Creating library build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\ibm_db.cp36-win32.lib and object build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\ibm_db.cp36-win32.exp
ibm_db.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SQLGetDiagRec@32
ibm_db.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SQLTablePrivilegesW@28
ibm_db.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SQLProcedureColumnsW@36
```

....and so on...

```
ibm_db.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SQLDriverConnectW@32
**build\lib.win32-3.6\ibm_db.cp36-win32.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 46 unresolved externals
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120**
```

I installed Visual Studio on my machine(Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools) as it was required and I got the error as mentioned.

My OS is : Windows 10 64bit

Can anybody please help on this ?

Comment: Looks like you didn't install the IBM Data Server client, or installed it incorrectly.

Comment: @mustaccio, Thanks for your reply, but I have installed IBM Data Server client and still No Luck. Kindly, please let me know if I need to set any ENV variable, if so, then how and where ?

Answer (score 0):

check the DB2 SQLLIB 32/64 bit,
I think you need 32 bit version like python.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually have found the resolution. I just uninstall my python 3.6 and reinstall python 3.4 and it actually solved the issue. I am now successfully able to download ibm_db module for python to work with.